# Puzzled with Java Inheritance Rules

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

In the code below I have the following problem:

I don't get the semantics of

`One hybrid = new Two();`

My understanding is that Java performs in this case a so called upcasting. 
That even if `hybrid` is declared as an instance of `One` it the compiler casted it to a `Two` instance.

Is this correct?

Therefore at #3 it calls the method `foo` of `Two`. So far so good.

At #5 things are getting mysterious for me:

Why in earth is the compiler calling the `bar` method of `One` instead of `Two`? What am I missing here?

Thanks

Marcel

```
class One {
  public One() {}
  public String foo() {return "One-foo";}
  public String bar(One o) {return "One-bar " + o.foo();}
};

class Two extends One {
  public Two() {}
  public String foo() {return "Two-foo";}
  public String bar(Two t) {return "Two-bar " + t.foo();}
};

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    One one = new One();
    Two two = new Two();
    One hybrid = new Two();

    System.out.println(one.foo());        // #1 One-foo
    System.out.println(two.foo());        // #2 Two-foo
    System.out.println(hybrid.foo());     // #3 Two-foo

    System.out.println(one.bar(two));     // #4 One-bar Two-foo
    System.out.println(hybrid.bar(two));  // #5 One-bar Two-foo
    System.out.println(two.bar(hybrid));  // #6 One-bar Two-foo
  }
}
```

I would expect the following output compared to the one below:

```
One-foo
Two-foo
Two-foo
One-bar Two-foo
Two-bar Two-foo
Two-bar Two-foo
```

The actual output:

```
One-foo
Two-foo
Two-foo
One-bar Two-foo
One-bar Two-foo
One-bar Two-foo
```

Comment: Try to use the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: The problem is that `bar(Two t)` doesn't override `bar(One o)`, it simply shadows it.

Comment: https://briangordon.github.io/2014/09/covariance-and-contravariance.html has the answers you are looking for, specifically: "Overriding methods" "If the argument types aren’t identical in the subclass then the method will be overloaded instead of overridden. You should always use the @Override annotation to ensure that this doesn’t happen accidentally."

Answer (score 2):

`String bar(Two t)` does NOT override `String bar(One o)`.

Comment: Is not the same true for foo() in class One and Two? Why is in case #3 then the foo method of Two called?

Comment: @MarcelSchaible because `foo()` has no argument. `bar()` has an argument and its type is not the same in both classes.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Now it made click in my head ;-)